# Getting two images to touch CSS

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to get two images to touch with CSS.

```
<div>
 <image src="scroll><br>
 <image src="scroll>
</div>


* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {font-family:Courier New, Courier New, Courier New;
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

When using this code I get
[image: problem]

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer, or provide more info regarding you last comment?

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to get to 1000

Comment: Sorry about the wait on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason they don't touch is because of line height. Images are inline by default, meaning the gap between text lines is still there. You have to turn this off. The better way is to make the images block, rather than inline:

```
img { display: block }
```

Or `inline-block`.

The other way is to set `line-height: 0` on the containing `div`

Be sure that you are also using the correct tag. Images use `<img>` not `<image>`

Comment: If I could give you the answer now I would but apparently I have to wait five minutes, thank you. I still have to change the margin on it to -2px to get them to butt up against each other but it worked nicely.

Comment: @Mr.Alien A larger font size increases the leading, yes. Some browsers do not allow font size to go below a certain vale for accessibility reasons, so you can't set the font size to zero to achieve the effect the asker wants.

Comment: @maxinfet avoid using negative margins, see what's the real issue here, if it's none from these than am sure your image is `png` and having a transparent canvas

Comment: @maxinfet you shouldn't have to set the margin. Be sure to remove the `<br>` and update the question with your current code, and I'll see what's wrong still.

Comment: @Nicholas sometimes setting `font-size: 0;` does the trick ;) but am sure there's some other issue here, probably canvas, after I read negative margin

Comment: @Mr.Alien that might work in your browser, but wouldn't work in mine. It cannot be relied upon, and is just a workaround for the real problem, when block images are inline.

Comment: @Nicholas yea kinda cross browser issue :p

Comment: @ Mr. Alien I am using a .png with transparent margins but I can't seem to find the extra space. There is no extra space showing in gimp and I have even attempted reducing the canvas size.

Answer (score 2):

Am not understanding which image are you talking about, no live example given, if it's the yellow 1 than why are you using `<br>`?

```
<div>
 <image src="#" />
 <image src="#" />
</div>
```

Also be sure you have resetted the default browser styles

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

If required also try setting `line-height: 0;` as Nicholas told you to do..

Answer (score 1):

either your image itself has extra spacing, or use this css:

```
img {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```